# Unable to get AD users/mailboxes created within a certain number of days using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Good morning. As the title states, the company I work for has a requirement to get a list of user accounts and mailboxes that were created over the last 30 days.

I am using the following Powershell script to achieve this, but I am NOT getting any results returned.

```
$lastday = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))
Get-ADUser -filter {(whencreated -ge $lastday)}
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That code should work just fine, but for the sake of readability i would remove the extra () in both lines.
You'll also want to add **-properties whencreated** so you can actually see the date of creation.

```
$lastday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-ADUser -filter {whencreated -ge $lastday} -properties whencreated
```

If you're not getting results that's because there's no users created in the past 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
$lastday = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties whencreated | Where-Object {$_.whencreated -ge $lastday}
```

If you don't get any results it means no AD user where crated in that period, or someone has deleted them.